# Not able to retrieve value from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in which some values are present i
 want to retrieve the `[0][1]` or `[1][1]` index value. I am getting
 undefined as array, if i tried to directly try to get the array value
 am able to get the value.

This what i want to achieve

I had a select drop down menu , According to the selected index i
 need to retrieve a message from the array box. For say if the index is
 1 then i had to get `[1][1]` array index value if it is zero then `[0][1]`
 array index value

This is the fiddle what i have done. http://jsfiddle.net/hTQZ9/

Comment: why do you create an array inside an array? just add a value to the index!

Comment: @Bergi am not able to retrieve the value from the array

Comment: @p0rter this mutlidimensional array is also being used at other places , that why it being created like this. to match the key with the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this update: http://jsfiddle.net/hTQZ9/1/

```
var MessagesObj = {
    testName: []
}
MessagesObj["testName"].push(["testName_custom_message_Label1val","Custom message for label 1"]);
MessagesObj["testName"].push(["testName_custom_message_Label2val","Custom message for label 2"]);

alert(MessagesObj["testName"][1][1]);

var classChk       = $(".customCheckEnabled").get(0);
var getClassindex  = classChk.selectedIndex;
var getVarName     = classChk.id
var getCstMsgName  = MessagesObj[getVarName];
alert(getCstMsgName);

var getMessage     = getCstMsgName[getClassindex][1];
alert(getMessage);
```

Comment: The array is already present in the database i cannot modify that

Answer (score 0):

getCstMsgName is a string, not an array.

One way is to use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var testName_MessagesArray = new Array();
    var cntr = 0;
    testName_MessagesArray[cntr] = new Array("testName_custom_message_Label1val", "Custom message for label 1");
    cntr++;
    testName_MessagesArray[cntr] = new Array("testName_custom_message_Label2val", "Custom message for label 2");
    cntr++;
    alert(testName_MessagesArray[1][1]);

    var classChk = $(".customCheckEnabled");
    alert(classChk);

    this.testName = testName_MessagesArray; //<-- set this with the name
    var getClassindex = classChk.attr("selectedIndex");
    alert(getClassindex);
    var getVarName = classChk.attr("id");
    alert(getVarName);
    var getCstMsgName = this[getVarName]; //<-- reference it from this
    alert(getCstMsgName);
    var getMessage = getCstMsgName[getClassindex][1];
    alert(getMessage);


});
```

​
If `testName_MessagesArray` is in global scope, you can do `window["testName_MessagesArray"]` to reference it. Your current example is local scope so that would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use an array literal instead of, er, `cntr`s:

```
var testName_MessagesArray = [
    ["testName_custom_message_Label1val", "Custom message for label 1"],
    ["testName_custom_message_Label2val", "Custom message for label 2"]
];
```

Then, if you want to retrieve a value from it, use `testName_MessagesArray[x][y]`.

What you were doing:

```
var classChk=$(".customCheckEnabled"); 
// this is a jQuery element, alerted as [object Object]

var getClassindex=classChk.attr("selectedIndex"); 
// this is 0 or 1

var getVarName=classChk.attr("id"); 
// this will be the id of the first selected element, a string

var getCstMsgName=getVarName+"_MessagesArray".toString();
// this will create a string, from the "getVarName"-string and your string-literal-toString

var getMessage=getCstMsgName[getClassindex][1];
// as "getCstMsgName" is a string - not the twodimensional array, 
// getCstMsgName[getClassindex] returns the character at the selected index (as a string)
// and getCstMsgName[getClassindex][1] results in the second character of the one-character-string - undefined
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for an example